# Case statement trickery required

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Table 1

```
Mail              Special Quote (Y/N)

g@hotmail.com     Blank 
s@ho.com          Blank
sss@j.com         Blank
```

Table 2

```
Email Address     Dept

g@hotmail.com     Config 
s@ho.com          Finance
sss@j.com         Marketing
```

Now I want Table 1 updated to Y where the matching email address in Table 2 is coming from `Finance` or `Marketing` .

```
UPDATE TABLE 1 
Set Special Quote to be Y 
where in TABLE 2 the Dept is Finance or Marketing for the matching email address.
```

Probably just having a brain freeze and need some coffee .

Thinking left join on email address then throw in a bit of a case statement perhaps for the Y and N bit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.SpecialQuote = 'Y'
FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN Table2 B
ON A.Mail = B.EmailAddress
WHERE B.Dept IN ('Finance','Marketing')
```

Answer (score 3):

no case statement needed.

```
update table1 set special_quote = 'Y'
where mail in ( select email_address from table2 where dept in ('Finance','Marketing' ))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm more of a MySQL user so this could be wrong, but try something like this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET specialquote = 'Y'
WHERE Mail IN (SELECT EmailAddress FROM table2 WHERE Dept IN ('Finance','Marketing'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close, you will need to join the two tables on the mail field but then check if the Dept is in Finance/Marketing

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.[Special Quote] = 'Y'
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.mail = t2.mail
WHERE t2.Dept in ('Finance','Marketing')
```

This will update only the items that are included, if you want to update either Y/N, then you could do the following (see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a5b6/11))

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.sq = CASE WHEN t2.dept IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM  table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2  t2
    ON t1.mail = t2.mail
    AND t2.Dept in ('Finance','Marketing')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.  Here is the syntax:

```
update table1
    set SpecialQuote = 'Y'
    where mail in (select emailaddress from table2 where dept in ('Finance', 'Marketing')
```

Answer (score 0):

Update Table1
   Set [Special Quote]='Y'
  from Table1 t1
  join Table2 t2
    on t1.[Email Address]=t2.[Email Address]
 where t2.dept in ('Finance','Marketing')

Untested sample, so understand that caveat, but believe it is close enough to illustrate the point. Good luck!

**EDIT**: Per the OP's "Y/N update" comment below, change as follows...although there are several other subtly different ways you could accomplish the same thing. Hope this helps you.

```
Update Table1
   Set [Special Quote]=(case when t2.dept='Finance' 
                             then 'Y'
                             when t2.dept='Marketing'
                             then 'Y'
                             else 'N' 
                        end) 
  from Table1 t1
  join Table2 t2
    on t1.[Email Address]=t2.[Email Address]
```

Comment: but, this doesn't update to 'N'. Of course, a second query could solve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #tbl1 (mail varchar(50),quote varchar(1))
create table #tbl2 (mail varchar(50),dept varchar(10))

insert into #tbl1 values ('a@a.com','')
insert into #tbl1 values ('b@b.com','')
insert into #tbl1 values ('c@c.com','')
insert into #tbl1 values ('d@d.com','')
insert into #tbl1 values ('e@e.com','')

insert into #tbl2 values ('a@a.com','config')
insert into #tbl2 values ('b@b.com','finance')
insert into #tbl2 values ('c@c.com','marketing')
insert into #tbl2 values ('d@d.com','other')
insert into #tbl2 values ('e@e.com','skivers')


update #tbl1
set quote = 'Y'
where mail in (SELECT mail FROM #tbl2 WHERE dept IN ('finance','marketing'))

select * from #tbl1

drop table #tbl1
drop table #tbl2
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to help clarify different pieces of a query, so here is one way to do this. There are others if you don't like it.

```
with getval as (
select mail,dept from test2
where dept in ('Marketing','Finance')
)


update test1
set quote = case when dept is NOT null then 'Y' else 'N' end 
from test1 t1
left outer join getval t2 on t1.mail = t2.mail
```

Anyway, I used a left join to take all of the records, then used a case to sort where the dept appeared (meaning the record was found in the CTE).

OR...

```
update table1
set quote = case when dept is NOT null then 'Y' else 'N' end 
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.email = t2.email and t2.dept in ('Marketing','Finance')
```

That should also work.